# How to "spread out" grid items horizontally?

Tags: css

I have a very simple grid:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import styled from '@emotion/styled';

import './style.css';

const GridContainer = styled('div')({
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)',
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>hello</div>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Result is:
[image]

Is there a way to spread the 3 divs so that the first on the left is at its current place, the second is in the middle of the whole width, and the third is sticking to the right?
And is it possible to do it within the grid container? And not manually to each div element

It would look like:

[image]

Comment: use auto instead of 1fr and add justify-content: space-between